# How to get Paths to all executables from Get-ChildItem

Tags: windows, powershell

I am currently trying to get a list of all installed applications and would like to build a feature that can launch those.

I'm using these PowerShell commands:

`gci HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\* | % { Get-ItemProperty $_.PsPath } | Select DisplayName,InstallLocation`

`gci HKLM:\\SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Uninstall\\* | % { Get-ItemProperty $_.PsPath } | Select DisplayName,InstallLocation`

in conjunction with `ConvertTo-Json` in order to get a good stdout I can work with.
Now, this only gives me the InstallPath without any executables.

Is there any easy way to get the main executable of the applications i nthe list?

Expected Result (Name of the key does not matter):

```json
    // ...
    {
        "DisplayName":  "Microsoft Edge",
        "InstallLocation":  "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft\\Edge\\Application",
        "LaunchApplication": "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft\\Edge\\Application\msedge.exe",
    },
    {
        "DisplayName":  "Audacity 2.4.2",
        "InstallLocation":  "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Audacity\\",
        "LaunchApplication": "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Audacity\\audacity.exe"
    },
    // ...
```

Comment: Why would you need to pipe to `ConvertTo-Json`?  Also, what do you mean by how the start menu does? What should be the expected result?

Comment: @AbrahamZinala I'm grabbing the list via `exec` and am outputting the list in an electron application, which is why I need it in json

Comment: @AbrahamZinala I added an expected Result

Comment: @AbrahamZinala I also edited the question to clarify

Comment: Unfortunately there is no standard way of getting executable paths of installed applications. You have to use heuristic approach by looking for start menu shortcuts (*.lnk) that point to executable(s) within InstallLocation.

Comment: As an aside: ``\`` chars. have no special meaning to PowerShell itself, and therefore generally don't require escaping as ``\\``.

Comment: @mklement0 good to know, but this is the actual output from convertTo-Json, which is why they are escaped I suppose

Comment: Yes, you're seeing _JSON_'s escaping rules, which are unrelated to PowerShell's; try `'a\b' | ConvertTo-Json`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Like others have pointed out in the comments, there isn't a conventional way of getting the executable paths of certain programs.

To answer your indirect question of building an app launch method, we can make use of a few *things*. Fortunately for us, PowerShell has a [`Get-StartApps`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/startlayout/get-startapps?view=windowsserver2022-ps) cmdlet that produces an output of the current users installed apps:

```
Name                                                 AppID
----                                                 -----
3D Viewer                                            Microsoft.Microsoft3DViewer_8wekyb3d8bbwe!Microsoft.Microsoft3DViewer
AdGuard                                              AdGuard
Adobe Acrobat DC                                     {6D809377-6AF0-444B-8957-A3773F02200E}\Adobe\Acrobat DC\Acrobat\Acrobat.exe
Battle.net                                           {7C5A40EF-A0FB-4BFC-874A-C0F2E0B9FA8E}\Battle.net\Battle.net Launcher.exe
Blend for Visual Studio 2022                         Blend.d58ce8bb
Calculator                                           Microsoft.WindowsCalculator_8wekyb3d8bbwe!App
Calendar                                             microsoft.windowscommunicationsapps_8wekyb3d8bbwe!microsoft.windowslive.calendar
```

There are 2 properties that are displayed:

- *Name*
- *AppID*.

This becomes important due to the AppID being the value needed for `shell:` to execute/launch the program. Given the above output of `Get-StartApps`, you can launch "Adobe Acrobat DC" by passing the AppID to `shell:\AppsFolder\"AppID"`.

```
Start-Process shell:AppsFolder\"{6D809377-6AF0-444B-8957-A3773F02200E}\Adobe\Acrobat DC\Acrobat\Acrobat.exe"
```

Using [@zett42's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7571258/zett42) approach, we can query your start menu, along with the system start menu folder paths for *.lnk's* retrieving its target path using the WScript COM object:

```
$paths = "C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs","$env:APPDATA\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu"
Get-ChildItem -Path $paths -Filter "*.lnk" -File -Recurse | 
    ForEach-Object -Begin {
        $WScriptShell = New-Object -ComObject "WScript.Shell"
    } -Process {
        [PSCustomObject]@{
            Name = $_.BaseName
            Path = $WScriptShell.CreateShortcut($_.FullName).TargetPath
        }
    } -End {
        [void][System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($WScriptShell) #release COM object
    }
```

which will output:

```
Name                         Path
----                         ----
Adobe Acrobat DC             C:\Program Files\Adobe\Acrobat DC\Acrobat\Acrobat.exe
Blend for Visual Studio 2022 C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\Common7\IDE\Blend.exe
Firefox                      C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe
Google Chrome                C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe
Microsoft Edge               C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Edge\Application\msedge.exe
TechPowerUp GPU-Z            C:\Program Files (x86)\GPU-Z\GPU-Z.exe
```

---

*Not entirely sure this is what you're after, but it may be of help to others.*

Comment: I get the output I require by appending `| ConvertTo-Json `. Thank you very much, good sir