# How can I launch an application via PowerShell in Windows using FolderItem Object

Tags: powershell, automation, powershell-cmdlet

I am collecting a list of names and paths from the following PowerShell code:

```
(new-object -com shell.application).namespace('shell:appsFolder').items()
```

I am able open each item using its invokeVerb() method or verb DoIt() method.

What I would like to do is to be able to discover the executable path for each item so that it can be opened outside of this context using the Start-Process cmdlet or any other more generic approach?

Is there a way to extract the executable path so that they can be opened outside of this specific context or a better way to go about collecting the information above in a way that can be used to launch the applications at a later time without having to rerun the above query to source the objects?

Ultimately, I'm looking to collect the same list of applications that return from the above code and index them so they can be launched programmatically outside of this context - so any suggestions or ideas around how to accomplish that would be helpful.

Comment: So, I believe you can just append the namepsace to the `.Path` property of those items, then those paths should work fine using `Start-Process`. i.e. for Calculator: `Start-Process 'shell:AppsFolder\Microsoft.WindowsCalculator_8wekyb3d8bbwe!App'`

Comment: something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71889808/14903754)?

Comment: @AbrahamZinala something like that

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon - Yes, I think this is exactly what I was looking for - thank you - I wasn't able to find the connection in my reading so far.  Thank you

Comment: @AbrahamZinala - This link is very helpful - thank you